# Get string from tkinter text object without line break

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a basic tkinter app where I prompt the user for a query and it outputs to to an excel file but when I try to get the value of the userinput I always get a linebreak. How do I avoid this?

```
...
Textinput = Text(app,width=68,height=5,yscrollcommand=sb2.set)
Textinput.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=colSpan,sticky=N)
compareButton = Button(text="Output to XLSX",command = lambda: exportToExcel(Textinput.get("1.0","end")))
...
```

Should I be using something other than "end" for the get command?
I have a workaround, but would prefer to solve the issue at its source.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `"end-1c"` for the second parameter to `.get()` to avoid the newline at the end (there may still be explicitly-typed newlines elsewhere in the string, if you don't want that then use an Entry rather than a Text).

Comment: Using "end-1c" fixed the issue.
Thank you for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

Add `.strip()` at the end of the `get` method:

```py
Button(text="Output to XLSX",command = lambda: pressing(Textinput.get("1.0","end").strip())).grid()
```

Or as @jasonharper suggested, use `Entry`:

```py
Textinput = Entry(app,width=68,height=5)
Textinput.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=N)
```

Comment: Using Strip resolved the issue, as did @jasonharper suggestion of using "end-1c"
Thank you for your prompt response

Comment: You're welcome. You could confirm the answer by clicking on the tick sign on the top left corner of the answer.